# How to correctly fix circular dependency on global variable?

Tags: c++

I've done some searching regarding circular dependencies but haven't found an answer when it comes to global variables. Here's what's going on, with the names simplified a bit:

- My global variables file (`globals.h`) has `#include A.h`
- `A.h` has `#include B.h`
- `B.h` has a reference to the global `const int Foo`, which is declared in `globals.h`

This gives me an error that `const int Foo` was not declared in scope. If I understand correctly, this is because `#include A.h` is run before `extern const int Foo` is defined.

What's the best way to fix this? If I put `extern const int Foo` in `B.h` before the class declaration, that fixes it, but isn't that the wrong way to use `extern` since it's already being used for that variable in `globals.h`? Is there a better way?

I imagine with better class design this might not be a problem at all, but at the moment, these dependencies aren't avoidable...just looking for some advice. Thanks much!!

P.S. As is probably evident from this post, I'm no C++ pro (my C++ experience is all hobby-related) and would love to hear any related advice in general to avoid this kind of problem in the future.

Comment: Aside from the question: don't use global variables

Comment: Context: This code is for a 2D platformer. Is it reasonable to get away with not using any global variables in something like that? I haven't found a good way to pass that kind of information (conveniently and cleanly, anyway) between several classes.

Comment: @PlanetLotus: Global constants are one thing.  Actual global variables should be eliminated ASAP (no exaggeration).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I'll look into that. For the several classes that constantly need access to some of these variables, is it best to add a member variable that references it, or is there a better way?

Comment: Are these compile-time constant ints? Put them in header files as `const int blah = 5;` or add static if they are in a class. Don't do that with other types, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Foo is a static const int, I would refactor your .h files so you have your static constants in a common place.  Be careful not to define the same variable twice.

Otherwise, making the header declare it was extern and putting the definition the appropriate .cpp file is fine.